# How to Sign In with Twitter using Firebase_Auth with Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, twitter-oauth

How should one program a **Sign In with Twitter** feature using [firebase_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth) and Flutter?

I see a few examples using [flutter_twitter_login](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_twitter_login) or [flutter_twitter](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_twitter), however they use a now [**Deprecated API**](https://blog.twitter.com/developer/en_us/topics/tools/2018/discontinuing-support-for-twitter-kit-sdk.html) and folks complain about [Apple Store Rejection](https://github.com/roughike/flutter_twitter_login/issues/19).

*Firebase Auth* offers a [TwitterAuthProvider](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/TwitterAuthProvider-class.html), but the following code remains incomplete:

```dart
final AuthCredential credential = TwitterAuthProvider.getCredential(
  authToken: twitterAccessToken,
  authTokenSecret: twitterAccessTokenSecret,
);
final AuthResult result = await auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
```

Comment: Apparently, "Apple will stop accepting submissions of apps that use UIWebView API."  This impacts the Facebook Login strategy too.  However, there is apparently a way to use Oauth + WebView + Server Code.  I would love to see a fleshed out Flutter + Firebase Auth example.  I did find this for reference: https://github.com/EmmanuelAmodu/Flutter-nodejs-facebook-auth

Comment: This [article](https://medium.com/@karlwhiteprivate/flutter-facebook-sign-in-with-firebase-in-2020-66556a8c3586) shows how one can authenticate with **Facebook** using `flutter_webview_plugin` and not the _deprecated_ `flutter_facebook_login`.  I am essentially seeking the equivalent guidance for Twitter.

Comment: what is the version of plugins you are using or have used ?

Comment: The latest packages; they haven't changed in a while.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to solve this using 3 resources:

1. The [Flutter Facebook Sign In (with Firebase) in 2020](https://medium.com/@karlwhiteprivate/flutter-facebook-sign-in-with-firebase-in-2020-66556a8c3586) article
2. The [Log in with Twitter](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/guides/log-in-with-twitter) guide
3. The [Dart OAuth1](https://github.com/nbspou/dart-oauth1) library

Ultimately, I was able to completely remove the [flutter_twitter](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_twitter) package, yet still support *Sign in with Twitter*.

Similar to the `CustomWebView` outlined in the Facebook solution, I created a `TwitterLoginScreen` like:

```dart
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_webview_plugin/flutter_webview_plugin.dart';
import 'package:oauth1/oauth1.dart';

/// Twitter Login Screen.
/// See [Log in with Twitter](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/guides/log-in-with-twitter).
class TwitterLoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final twitterPlatform = Platform(
    'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token', // temporary credentials request
    'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize', // resource owner authorization
    'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token', // token credentials request
    SignatureMethods.hmacSha1, // signature method
  );

  final ClientCredentials clientCredentials;
  final String oauthCallbackHandler;

  TwitterLoginScreen({
    @required final String consumerKey,
    @required final String consumerSecret,
    @required this.oauthCallbackHandler,
  }) : clientCredentials = ClientCredentials(consumerKey, consumerSecret);

  @override
  _TwitterLoginScreenState createState() => _TwitterLoginScreenState();
}

class _TwitterLoginScreenState extends State<TwitterLoginScreen> {
  final flutterWebviewPlugin = FlutterWebviewPlugin();

  Authorization _oauth;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Initialize Twitter OAuth
    _oauth = Authorization(widget.clientCredentials, widget.twitterPlatform);

    flutterWebviewPlugin.onUrlChanged.listen((url) {
      // Look for Step 2 callback so that we can move to Step 3.
      if (url.startsWith(widget.oauthCallbackHandler)) {
        final queryParameters = Uri.parse(url).queryParameters;
        final oauthToken = queryParameters['oauth_token'];
        final oauthVerifier = queryParameters['oauth_verifier'];
        if (null != oauthToken && null != oauthVerifier) {
          _twitterLogInFinish(oauthToken, oauthVerifier);
        }
      }
    });

    _twitterLogInStart();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    flutterWebviewPlugin.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> _twitterLogInStart() async {
    assert(null != _oauth);
    // Step 1 - Request Token
    final requestTokenResponse =
        await _oauth.requestTemporaryCredentials(widget.oauthCallbackHandler);
    // Step 2 - Redirect to Authorization Page
    final authorizationPage = _oauth.getResourceOwnerAuthorizationURI(
        requestTokenResponse.credentials.token);
    flutterWebviewPlugin.launch(authorizationPage);
  }

  Future<void> _twitterLogInFinish(
      String oauthToken, String oauthVerifier) async {
    // Step 3 - Request Access Token
    final tokenCredentialsResponse = await _oauth.requestTokenCredentials(
        Credentials(oauthToken, ''), oauthVerifier);

    final result = TwitterAuthProvider.getCredential(
      authToken: tokenCredentialsResponse.credentials.token,
      authTokenSecret: tokenCredentialsResponse.credentials.tokenSecret,
    );

    Navigator.pop(context, result);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WebviewScaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Twitter Login")),
      url: "https://twitter.com",
    );
  }
}
```

Then, the `AuthCredential` result from this screen can be passed to [FirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/signInWithCredential.html).

Comment: I used your solution, but I am facing few issues:
1.  flutterWebviewPlugin.launch(authorizationPage); is throwing error so I had to use .reload()
2. it is taking almost 2-3 minutes for callback URL to get called.
did you face this?
how did you solve it?

Comment: I did not experience the issue you described.  I recommend double checking your configuration inputs like `consumerKey`, `consumerSecret`, and `oauthCallbackHandler`.

Comment: what is the version of each plugin you are using ?

Comment: How did you get the oauthCallbackHandler? It's not the callback url firebase auth provides on their config page, correct? (https://myapp.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler)

Comment: @duffy did you figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

To sign in with Twitter do the following:

```
 Future<FirebaseUser> loginWithTwitter() async {
  var twitterLogin = new TwitterLogin(
    consumerKey: 'key',
    consumerSecret: 'secretkey',
  );

  final TwitterLoginResult result = await twitterLogin.authorize();

switch (result.status) {
  case TwitterLoginStatus.loggedIn:
    var session=result.session;
    final AuthCredential credential= TwitterAuthProvider.getCredential(
      authToken: session.token,
      authTokenSecret: session.secret
    );
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser=(await firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
    print("twitter sign in"+firebaseUser.toString());
    break;
  case TwitterLoginStatus.cancelledByUser:
    break;
  case TwitterLoginStatus.error:
    break;
}
```

Use `twitterlogin` and pass the consumer key and consumer secret key, then use the method `getCredential()` and `signInWithCredential` to log in.

Comment: This relies on TwitterKit, which has been deprecated.  Is there not a more future proof strategy?

Comment: currently this is the only way, it will work on android but ios yes it wont work since it is deprecated as you said

Comment: For the record, YES, I have tried the proposed `TwitterLogin` strategy, and I managed to get it to work for both Android and iOS.  I am still concerned that this strategy uses a **deprecated** API, yet **there does not seem to be a better, _supported_ solution**.  (I have not received any Store submission feedback yet; I may still run into problems.)

Answer (score 0):

They have shared a common sample in the home page itself, only the 'sign in provider' changes, rest is same for all (google, fb and twitter). the result has a user property which will return the user details, check with the below code

```
final AuthCredential credential = TwitterAuthProvider.getCredential(
  authToken: twitterAccessToken,
  authTokenSecret: twitterAccessTokenSecret,
);
final AuthResult result = await auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
final FirebaseUser user = result.user;
print("signed in " + user.displayName);
```

Comment: This code does not provide any interface to capture Twitter username/password credentials, and authenticates instead as the App.  What is missing for that?

Comment: twitter / fb / google user name / passwords are never exposed by firebase, you can use the api to validate the user as twitter user and then use his profile information like display name / email / mobile (if it is shared) in your app

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. (Referred from https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/social#twitter)

```
import 'package:twitter_login/twitter_login.dart';

Future<UserCredential> signInWithTwitter() async {
  // Create a TwitterLogin instance
  final twitterLogin = new TwitterLogin(
    apiKey: '<your consumer key>',
    apiSecretKey:' <your consumer secret>',
    redirectURI: '<your_scheme>://'
  );

  // Trigger the sign-in flow
  final authResult = await twitterLogin.login();

  // Create a credential from the access token
  final twitterAuthCredential = TwitterAuthProvider.credential(
    accessToken: authResult.authToken!,
    secret: authResult.authTokenSecret!,
  );

  // Once signed in, return the UserCredential
  return await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(twitterAuthCredential);
}
```

This wasn't working initially for me.

Things I had to change in order for this to work.

1. Request for Elevated Permissions in Twitter Developer Portal.
2. Create a custom scheme (callback URL) and configure the ios/android files accordingly. As given in (https://pub.dev/packages/twitter_login).
3. Also configure this callback URL in the Twitter dev portal.

Answer (score 0):

I recently developed a plugin for twitter login that is easy to use and is working fine. The plugin is [twitter_auth_firebase](https://pub.dev/packages/twitter_auth_firebase).

**You just have to use this line.**

```
final Map<Object?, Object?>? result = await TwitterAuthFirebase.loginViaTwitter();
```

**and in result you will get:**

```
bool? success = result["success"]; // Indicates success
String? message = result["message"]; // Message for success and error
Map<Object?, Object?>? profileData = result["profile"]; // User's Twitter profile data on success
String? idToken = result["idToken"]; // User's ID token
String? accessToken = result["accessToken"]; // User's access token
Map<Object?, Object?>? error = result["error"]; // Error object, if any
```

**Note:-This plugin only works if you are implementing twitter auth using firebase.**