# How to sign in with Twitter on Flutter for web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have a flutter project for Android, iOS and web.
I would like to sign in to my app with twitter on Flutter for **web**.

Dart library [twitter_login](https://pub.dev/packages/twitter_login) is subject to Android and iOS, not to web.
I tried to twitter [sign in without "twitter_login"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60461547/how-to-sign-in-with-twitter-using-firebase-auth-with-flutter).
Though that way needs listen to change of URL, I cannot find the way to listen to change of URL with IFrame Element, because WebView plugin is only for Android and iOS.

Could you please let me know the way?